# Shell script compare .conf values

Tags: shell, comparison

if have my .conf file:

```
M_DUMP_DB="testing"
```

now in my .sh file I want to check if the field equals to "testing"

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/.../conf_name.conf
echo $M_DUMP_DB
# outputs "testing"
if [ "$M_DUMP_DB" = "testing" ]; then
    echo "Condition has met"
fi
```

And comparison never results in true, but if I assign the variable inside the script comparison result is true.

Comment: Works OK with the 1 line in a .conf file; maybe there's something interfering within your .conf file?  What does the comparison look like when running your script with `bash -x` ?

Comment: agree with above, OR does your `.conf` file have `\r\n` line endings? Check with `cat -vet my.conf`. If you see `^M$` at the end of lines, fix the file with `dos2unix my.conf`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, to be honest that was something I wasn't able to fix searching the web, it is working as intended now, thanks for the knowledge and time.